# Laravel / Google API / Ajax: How to update marker's latitude and longitude when dragged

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-api

I'm having trouble on how to send the marker coordinates to controller using ajax.

I have my routes named as 'update-marker-position' and I put csrf_token() too but it still displays error message in logs.

web.php

```
Route::post('/update-marker-position', [MarkerController::class, 'updatePosition'])->name('update-marker-position');
```

Here is my code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
                const newLat = event.latLng.lat();
                const newLng = event.latLng.lng();
                const markerTitle = marker.getTitle();
                  

                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: '{{ route('update-marker-position') }}',
                    data: {
                        _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                        title: markerTitle,
                        lat: newLat,
                        lng: newLng
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log('Successfully updated:', response);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.error('Error:', error);
                    }
                });


            // console.log('Shop:', markerTitle,' Latitude: ', newLat,' Longitude: ', newLng);

            });
```

error in logs

```
500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check server error in DevTools -> Go to Network Tab and Select Fetch/XHR results  from filters, then select request with 500 status and then go to Preview to see server error details